# Jiobook flashing

Tags: android, arm, flashing

I have a jiobook 2023, I want to flash a costume rom in it. Specifically ubuntu touch. Is there any way to flash?

Flashing laptops by going into bios mode doesn't work. It is more like a Android mobile without volume buttons.